# Achieving monospaced text in card text

Tags: google-hangouts

I would like to know if it's possible to send a monospaced block in a card or textParagraph.

I tried ```` ``` ```` but didn't work, and neither did `<span>` with a `style` attribute.

Ex:

````
{
    "cards": {
        "sections": {
            "widgets": {
                "textParagraph": {
                    "text": "This is a code:<br>```print('hi')```"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
````

How can I include monospaced text in a card?

Comment: What does it have to do with C? Looks like an HTML question to me

Comment: definitely a typo, sorry haha
Well, it's a Google Hangout API question :P

Comment: https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/cards#card_text_formatting

Comment: I did read their documentation, and since it's pretty bad I decided to ask here.
Probably there's another way to add those blocks, or some special element in the JSON that is not listed there.

Comment: Bad?! It says you can only augment the text using certain HTML tags and proceeds to list them, and it specifically says this is different than the text body of a basic message which "is parsed using a different markup syntax" and links to a page that show the triple backticks part of that syntax.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/cards#card_text_formatting), this isn't possible. It states that card text can only be augmented via a small subset of HTML tags, none of which can produce the desired result. It specifically notes that this differs from the text body of basic messages, which uses a syntax that supports triple backticks.

Furthermore, none of the documented widgets could be used to achieve the desired effect either.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm looking for a possible solution for that. Isn't there any element that I could add to the card in order to get a code block?

Comment: The problem is that I can't change the font.

Comment: Indeed. I saw `font` in the list, but didn't notice it can only be used to change the colour. Fixed the question and updated the answer to match.